# I wanna put an xml file content into a URL, can I?

Tags: iphone, xml, url-scheme

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"appName://<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"];
```

But the url = nil. I found if I remove the "<" and ">" signs, it will be ok.
So, the two signs cannot be used in a URL? Should I replace the signs with another one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem.
Before I do NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"...."];
I first do:

```
    NSString *urlStr = [string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

And when parse this url on the receiver side, I firstly do:

```
NSString *urlString = [[url absoluteString] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; // url is a NSURL
```

Answer (score 1):

Why would you not just POST the document in the body of the request?

GET requests are not designed for this. You may get into difficulty if there are UTF-8 chars in the document.

Also [What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url) implies a max of 2083 chars.

You're into a very browser/proxy dependent scenario.

Comment: Well, I'm not using in a http protocal, I just want to call my app from another app by openurl. And pass it some complicated params, which I think xml is better. So, how can I pass this xml via a url?

Comment: sorry, I missed that part. Your escaping suggestion should work and I haven't heard of any limits on the url length. Would the clipboard also be an option for larger data structure?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically yes. You can use urlEncode to do this.
The HTTP protocol does not place any limit on the length of the URL.

RFC says:

> Note: Servers ought to be cautious about depending on URI lengths
>   above 255 bytes, because some older client or proxy implementations
>   might not properly support these lengths.